# Please explain when duplicate names on controls is permitted

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form, with a tab control, with two tabs.

Each tab has a "cancel button".

I tried to name each of them `btn_cancel` but it won't let me because they would have the same name.

However, they both have different "parents", no?  So one is `tabPage1.btn_cancel` and the other is `tabPage2.btn_cancel` in my mind...

Can someone please clear up my confusion?

Answer (score 4):

This is not allowed because they are both defined as variables on the same class, which is your form.

Check the your form's designer.cs file, it will have declarations like that:

```
partial class Form1
{
    //... more generated code

    private System.Windows.Forms.Button btn_cancel1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button btn_cancel2;
}
```

Comment: As simple as your answer is, you can tell my mind was clouded.  Makes total sense.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

They both have the same scope.  If you create separate controls for your tab pages, you will be able to have names scoped locally to those controls.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the two controls and tie them both to the same event if they need to perform the same task. In VB e.g. one adds `() Handles ctrl.click, ctrl2.click` to the end of the click event.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles Button2.Click, Button1.Click
    'cancel stuff
End Sub
```